# SpeechRecognizer ERROR_NO_MATCH with VlingoVoiceRecognitionService

Tags: android, speech-recognition, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have created a SpeechRecognizer implementation that works great on everything except a Samsung Galaxy S3, where no matter what, i'm receiving ERROR_NO_MATCH on every listen.
The only thing I can think of is that this is happening as a result of Samsung's Vlingo versus the Google Voice Search on the working phones.
Does anyone know about this or even have a fix?

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the Samsung S3 GT-I9300. Everything worked fine on that device running Android 4.0.4, then when updated to 4.1.2 I and started getting ERROR_NO_MATCH. I've heard the same things happens on a BB10. My LG mobile, running Android 4.1.2, works fine.